# Looking for a script or batch file to sort pictures in the main directory into their respective subdirectories based on partial filename

Tags: windows, batch-file, rename

I have the files named as such that is divided into three parts that are separated by hyphens.

```
Motorcycle-001-01.jpg
Motorcycle-001-02.jpg
Motorcycle-001-03.jpg

Motorcycle-002-01.jpg
Motorcycle-002-02.jpg
Motorcycle-002-03.jpg
```

The first part of the filename denotes the contect, which are pictures of motorcycles. The second part is the series while the third part is the individual picture within the series.

I have an entire directory called Motorcycles with 6,000 or so pictures named this way going all the way to Motorcycle-238-150.jpg

My question is if there is a batch file or script that I can use to sort these files using the series number, or the second part of the file. I would like all the files in my motorcycle directory to be moved into subdirectories within the motorcycle directory. For example, I would like Motorcycle-001-01.jpg through Motorcycle-001-150.jpg to be moved into directory 001. Then Motorcycle-002-01.jpg to Motorcycle-002-135.jpg to moved into directory 002 and so forth.

Comment: see my answer, if you want an automatized code just tell me and I can do it in a minutes

Comment: If you're looking for a script that somebody else has written, then this belongs on serverfault. StackOverflow is for writing it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Echo OFF

   :: By Elektro H@cker

REM Series:
REM If you type "1"   it's equals to serie "001"
REM If you type "10"  it's equals to serie "010"
REM If you type "100" it's equals to serie "100"
REM You can change that at the pattern multi-comparisions

:: Introduces a number of serie...
:SELECT
Set /P "Serie=Select the serie to move >>"

:: Basic error handling
Echo "%SERIE%" | FINDSTR /I "[a-z]" 1>NUL && (
    Echo [-] Type only nums...
    Set "Serie="
    GOTO:SELECT
)

:: Set the correct pattern for selected serie
IF %SERIE% LEQ 999 IF %SERIE% GTR 99 (Set "PATTERN=%SERIE%")
IF %SERIE% LEQ 99  IF %SERIE% GTR 9  (Set "PATTERN=0%SERIE%")
IF %SERIE% LSS 999 IF %SERIE% LSS 99 IF %SERIE% LEQ 9 (Set "PATTERN=00%SERIE%")

:: Makes the serie directory
MKDIR ".\%PATTERN%\" 2>NUL

:: Move all the files of the serie to the folder
For /F "Tokens=*" %%@ in ('DIR /B "Motorcycle-%PATTERN%*"') do (
    Move "%%@" ".\%PATTERN%\" >NUL
    Echo [+] Moved: %%@
)

Pause&Exit
```